# MVC: Design strategy for dynamic content not bound to single page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My site has an ever increasing number of distinct controllers, based around specific entities, which implement the Interface/Repository pattern to populate the various views. Most of these views are bound to single pages. Details, Indexes etc.

This entity data will also be displayed, mostly in summarised/compacted form, on other pages such as a customised home page, and side bars (using layouts and sections).

I'm uncertain as to which approach to use. I have 2 in mind:

1) Import the relevant repositories into the page template/sidebar template:

```
    public HomeController(IMessagesRepository messagesRepository, ICruiseCalendarRepository cruiseCalendarRepository, INewsRepository newsRepository, and so on and so on...)
    //
    {
        this.repoMessages = messagesRepository;
        this.repoCruiseCalendar = cruiseCalendarRepository;
        this repoNews = newsRepository;
        and so on
        and on
        ....
        ....
    }
```

...and build the page from these or.

2) Access the dynamic data through the controllers by use of Html.RenderAction:

```
<div class="newsBox">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("CustomisedHeadlines", "News");}
</div>
<div class="messageBox">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("LatestMessages", "Messages");}
</div>
<div class="calendarBox">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("WeekItinerary", "CruiseCalendar");}
</div>
```

Any suggestions as to the best design practice, would be welcome.

regards, Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Html.RenderAction` is definitely better solution. Its make controller simple and reuseble. You can easily add and remove boxes from view without changes in controller. It is easy to put them in diffrent view. Generally it's more flexible solution.